# Multi-level counter iteration

Tags: algorithm

I'm stuck on creating an algorithm as follows. I know this shouldn't be too difficult, but I simply can't get my head around it, and can't find the right description of this kind of pattern.

Basically I need a multi-level counter, where when a combination exist in the database, the next value is tried by incrementing from the right.

```
1 1 1 - Start position. Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
1 1 2 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
1 1 3 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
1 1 4 - Does this exist in database? NO -> Reset level 1, move to level 2
1 2 1 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
1 2 2 - Does this exist in database? NO -> Reset level 2 and 1, move to level 3
2 1 1 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
2 1 2 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
2 1 3 - Does this exist in database? NO -> Reset level 1 and increment level 2
2 2 1 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
2 2 2 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
2 2 3 - Does this exist in database? YES -> Extract this and go to next
2 3 1 - Does this exist in database? NO -> Extract this and go to next
3 1 1 - Does this exist in database? NO -> Extract this and go to next
3 2 1 - Does this exist in database? NO -> End, as all increments tried
```

There could be more than three levels, though.

In practice, each value like 1, 2, etc is actually a $value1, $value2, etc. containing a runtime string being matched against an XML document. So it's not just a case of pulling out every combination already existing in the database.

Comment: Why can't you do literally what you're describing?  i.e. iterate the least-significant digit, and if that's out of range, then reset it and increment the next digit instead.

Comment: The problem is the need for the algorithm to work backwards, e.g. to reset multiple levels, e.g. where 231 rolls up to 311. If there were four levels, it could be something like 4231 rolling to 4311. Actually, yes, maybe this has been staring me in the face, in that the rollover can always reset the least significant digits after it to 1.

Comment: `There could be more than three levels, though.` is it known in advance how many total levels exist? If no, then what is a stop condition of the algorithm?

Comment: Please clarify why 2.3.1 not found leads to trying 3.1.1 and not 2.4.1. Are maximums for each digit known in advance?

Comment: @tucuxi if my understanding is correct, the max value for each digit is _not_ know in advance, but inferred from the document.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko but from the example, every time we did not find a key, we incremented the 2nd level. `2.3.1 NO -> 3.1.1` marks the first transition where the 3rd level is incremented. I expected to see `2.3.1 NO -> 2.4.1 NO -> 3.1.1`, and the general rule `while no keys found, increment next level and reset all lower levels`

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming, the length of the DB key is known upfront, here's one way how it can be implemented**. I'm using TypeScript but similar code can be written in your favorite language.

First, I declare some type definitions for convenience.

```
export type Digits = number[];
export type DbRecord = number;
```

Then I initialize `fakeDb` object which works as a mock data source. The function I wrote will work against this object. This object's keys are representing the the database records' keys (of type `string`). The values are simple numbers (intentionally sequential); they represent the database records themselves.

```
export const fakeDb: { [ dbRecordKey: string ]: DbRecord } = {
  '111': 1,
  '112': 2,
  '113': 3,
  '211': 4,
  '212': 5,
  '221': 6,
  '311': 7,
};
```

Next, you can see **the fun part**, which is the function that uses `counterDigits` array of "digits" to increment depending on whether the record presence or absence.

Please, do **NOT** think this is the **production-ready code!** A) there are unnecessary `console.log()` invocations which only exist for demo purposes. B) it's a good idea to not read a whole lot of `DbRecords` from the database into memory, but rather use `yield/return` or some kind of buffer or stream.

```
export function readDbRecordsViaCounter(): DbRecord[] {
  const foundDbRecords: DbRecord[] = [];

  const counterDigits: Digits = [1, 1, 1];
  let currentDigitIndex = counterDigits.length - 1;

  do {
    console.log(`-------`);

    if (recordExistsFor(counterDigits)) {
      foundDbRecords.push(extract(counterDigits));

      currentDigitIndex = counterDigits.length - 1;
      counterDigits[currentDigitIndex] += 1;
    } else {
      currentDigitIndex--;
      for (let priorDigitIndex = currentDigitIndex + 1; priorDigitIndex < counterDigits.length; priorDigitIndex++) {
        counterDigits[priorDigitIndex] = 1;
      }
      if (currentDigitIndex < 0) {
        console.log(`------- (no more records expected -- ran out of counter's range)`);
        return foundDbRecords;
      }
      counterDigits[currentDigitIndex] += 1;
    }

    console.log(`next key to try: ${ getKey(counterDigits) }`);

  } while (true);
}
```

The remainings are some "helper" functions for constructing a string key from a digits array, and accessing the fake database.

```
export function recordExistsFor(digits: Digits): boolean {
  const keyToSearch = getKey(digits);
  const result = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fakeDb).some(key => key === keyToSearch);
  console.log(`key=${ keyToSearch } => recordExists=${ result }`);
  return result;
}

export function extract(digits: Digits): DbRecord {
  const keyToSearch = getKey(digits);
  const result = fakeDb[keyToSearch];
  console.log(`key=${ keyToSearch } => extractedValue=${ result }`);
  return result;
}

export function getKey(digits: Digits): string {
  return digits.join('');
}
```

---

Now, if you run the function like this:

```
const dbRecords = readDbRecordsViaCounter();
console.log(`\n\nDb Record List: ${ dbRecords }`);
```

you should see the following output that tells you about the iteration steps; as well as reports the final result in the very end.

> ```
> -------
> key=111 => recordExists=true
> key=111 => extractedValue=1
> next key to try: 112
> -------
> key=112 => recordExists=true
> key=112 => extractedValue=2
> next key to try: 113
> -------
> key=113 => recordExists=true
> key=113 => extractedValue=3
> next key to try: 114
> -------
> key=114 => recordExists=false
> next key to try: 121
> -------
> key=121 => recordExists=false
> next key to try: 211
> -------
> key=211 => recordExists=true
> key=211 => extractedValue=4
> next key to try: 212
> -------
> key=212 => recordExists=true
> key=212 => extractedValue=5
> next key to try: 213
> -------
> key=213 => recordExists=false
> next key to try: 221
> -------
> key=221 => recordExists=true
> key=221 => extractedValue=6
> next key to try: 222
> -------
> key=222 => recordExists=false
> next key to try: 231
> -------
> key=231 => recordExists=false
> next key to try: 311
> -------
> key=311 => recordExists=true
> key=311 => extractedValue=7
> next key to try: 312
> -------
> key=312 => recordExists=false
> next key to try: 321
> -------
> key=321 => recordExists=false
> next key to try: 411
> -------
> key=411 => recordExists=false
> ------- (no more records expected -- ran out of counter's range)
>
>
> Db Record List: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
> ```

---

It is strongly recommended to read the code. If you want me to describe the approach or any specific detail(s) -- let me know. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks - this looks very impressive. I'll take a look next week when I'm back in and working on this, but wanted to thank you initially now.

Comment: @fooquency did you have a chance to look into the sample provided?